# capturing and sending logcat output by email or to server

Tags: android, logging

I'm developing an Android app which has some complex logic and I am having issues troubleshooting the app that has been installed by beta-testers.

Does anyone know if there's an easy way to capture logcat output and either manually or automatically email it back, or send it to a server?  I have asked the person testing the app to install aLogcat app and send me the log, but there are 2 issues with this:

1. it sends all kinds of logging from other apps that I'm not intested
   in
2. it captures a limited amount of log entries, and did not give the
   log entries I needed.

If anyone has any experience with a similar problem and how to solve this, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Acra](http://acra.ch/). I have used and it is great. It can send the crashreport to a GDoc.

I'm pretty sure there are other tools too, and I think since Android 2.2 google has something built-in but I haven't found any docs about it. ([Android Error reports](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/google-feedback-for-android.html)).

Comment: Can I use Acra to capture and send back logcat entries instead of just exceptions?

Comment: Yes you can. Check their docs. http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#Sending_reports_for_caught_exceptions_or_for_unexpected_applicat

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Bugfender](https://bugfender.com). It lets you send all logs to a centralized cloud server, completely managed by you, no need for the user to intervene.

**Note:** I am one of the creators of Bugfender, still I think this could help solve question.